# PyTorch Image Classification with custom Dataset

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm still a beginner in terms of AI and Neuronal Networks and during the time this time of learning I'm trying to do some examples but I have a problem and no idea how can I fix it. If any of you would be able to help me, I would be really grateful.

**What I'm trying to do?**

A simple image classification with 10 types of animals using PyTorch with some custom Dataset.

**My images**

Each image is going to be with a shape as (3, 200, 200)

Also I have something like 40 images on each folder (train and test)

**How dose it look my data folders?**

- train

  - cat
  - dog
  - ...
  - rat
- test

  - cat
  - dog
  - ...
  - rat

**My model**

```
class NetModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(NetModel, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 6, 5)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 5)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16 * 5 * 5, 120)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 84)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        x = x.view(-1, 16 * 5 * 5)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x


def train_model(model, train_loader, optimizer, criterion, epochs, save_path):
    for epoch in range(epochs):  # loop over the dataset multiple times
        running_loss = 0.0
        for i, data in enumerate(train_loader, 0):
            # get the inputs; data is a list of [inputs, labels]
            inputs, labels = data
            # zero the parameter gradients
            optimizer.zero_grad()

            # forward + backward + optimize
            outputs = model(inputs)
            loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

            # print statistics
            running_loss += loss.item()
            if i % 2000 == 1999:  # print every 2000 mini-batches
                print('[%d, %5d] loss: %.3f' %
                      (epoch + 1, i + 1, running_loss / 2000))
                running_loss = 0.0
    print('Finished Training')
    # PATH = './cifar_net.pth'
    torch.save(model.state_dict(), save_path)
    print('Saved in: {}'.format(save_path))


def test(model, test_loader, classes, saved_path):
    model.load_state_dict(torch.load(saved_path))

    dataiter = iter(test_loader)
    images, labels = dataiter.next()

    print('GroundTruth: ', ' '.join('%5s' % classes[labels[j]] for j in range(4)))

    outputs = model(images)

    _, predicted = torch.max(outputs, 1)

    print('Predicted: ', ' '.join('%5s' % classes[predicted[j]] for j in range(4)))


transform = transforms.Compose(
    [transforms.ToTensor(),
     transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))])

charset = string.ascii_letters + "-' "
trainset = TESNamesDataset('../data/train', charset, 10)
testset = TESNamesDataset('../data/test', charset, 10)


trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=4,
                                          shuffle=True, num_workers=2)

testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(testset, batch_size=4,
                                         shuffle=False, num_workers=2)

model = NetModel()

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)

path = "../check_point/saved_model.pth"
train_model(model, trainloader, optimizer, criterion, 100, path)
test(model, testloader, animals, path)
```

**My custom dataset**

```
class TESNamesDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, data_root, charset, length):
        self.data_root = data_root
        self.charset = charset + '\0'
        self.length = length
        self.samples = []
        self.char_codec = LabelEncoder()
        self._init_dataset()

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.samples)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        name, pixels = self.samples[idx]
        return self.one_hot_sample(name), pixels

    def _init_dataset(self):
        names = set()
        # self.samples = []
        for animal in os.listdir(self.data_root):
            animal_filepath = os.path.join(self.data_root, animal)
            names.add(animal)
            for img_name in os.listdir(animal_filepath):
                img_path = os.path.join(animal_filepath, img_name)
                im = cv2.imread(img_path)
                if len(animal) < self.length:
                    animal += '\0' * (self.length - len(animal))
                else:
                    animal = animal[:self.length - 1] + '\0'
                self.samples.append((animal, im))

        self.char_codec.fit(list(self.charset))

    def to_one_hot(self, codec, values):
        value_idxs = codec.transform(values)
        return torch.eye(len(codec.classes_))[value_idxs]

    def one_hot_sample(self, name):
        t_name = self.to_one_hot(self.char_codec, list(name))
        return t_name
```

**The ERROR message**

> RuntimeError: Expected 4-dimensional input for 4-dimensional weight 6
>   3 5 5, but got 3-dimensional input of size [4, 10, 56] instead

Can any of you tell me what I'm doing wrong? In case that this question is off-topic just let me know where I can ask it.

Thanks